# Threadpool unable to create native thread

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to implement mergesort in various ways. I did implement it with `fork/join` and now I want to implement it using `ExecutorService` and `Threadpool`.

and what I'm currently at is the following:

```
public class Test<T> implements Comparable<T> {

private final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public Test() {
        //having this kind of threadpool prevent the program from generating any output whatsoever.
        //executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
   }


private void divide(LinkedList<T> dataToBeSorted) {
    if (dataToBeSorted.size() < 2) {
        return;
    }

    int mid = dataToBeSorted.size() / 2;
    LinkedList<T> left = new LinkedList<>(dataToBeSorted.subList(0, mid));
    LinkedList<T> right = new LinkedList<>(dataToBeSorted.subList(mid, dataToBeSorted.size()));

    Future<?> f1= (executor.submit(() -> divide(left)));
    Future<?> f2= (executor.submit(() -> divide(right)));

    try {

        f1.get();
        f2.get();

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("something went wrong went to sequential merge sort!");
        new SeqMergeSorter<T>().sort(dataToBeSorted);
        return;
    }

    merge(left, right, dataToBeSorted);
}



public static<T> void sort(LinkedList<T> dataToBeSorted){
    if (dataToBeSorted.size() < 2)
        return;
    var temp=new Test<T>();
    temp.divide(dataToBeSorted);
    temp.executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

### **Edit section:**

the above code has been updated.

- I added the `future` and i tried to shut it down in a separate method.
  now im getting a sorted elements but as long as my device can produce threads.
- due to the fact that `newCachedThreadPool` produce unlimited threads and cancel them after `60s` Im getting a the following output:

  `[1.427s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.`
- when changing the `newCachedThreadPool` to `newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())`i will get no output what so ever!.

Comment: `executor.execute()` does not wait for the given task to finish. It will be executed "some time" in the future, maybe even on a different thread. So your `merge()` method might not have the correct values yet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing is the following:

- I added the future and i tried to shut it down in a separate method. now im getting a sorted elements but as long as my device can produce threads.
- I used the `newWorkStealingPool` which by using the work stealing concept allowed me to sort big data without encountering memory problems.

**my Solution ended up like this:**

```
public class ExecutorMergeSorter<T> implements Comparable<T> {

private final ExecutorService excr;

public ExecutorMergeSorter() {
    excr = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
}

private void divide(LinkedList<T> dataToBeSorted) {
    if (dataToBeSorted.size() < 2) {
        return;
    }

    int mid = dataToBeSorted.size() / 2;
    LinkedList<T> left = new LinkedList<>(dataToBeSorted.subList(0, mid));
    LinkedList<T> right = new LinkedList<>(dataToBeSorted.subList(mid, dataToBeSorted.size()));

    Future<?> f1= (excr.submit(() -> divide(left)));
    Future<?> f2= (excr.submit(() -> divide(right)));

    try {

        f1.get();
        f2.get();

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        new SeqMergeSorter<T>().sort(dataToBeSorted);
    }

    merge(left, right, dataToBeSorted);
}



public static<T> void sort(LinkedList<T> dataToBeSorted){
    if (dataToBeSorted.size() < 2)
        return;
    var temp=new ExecutorMergeSorter<T>();
    temp.divide(dataToBeSorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is multi thread and create lot of intermediate data structure, please understand it will be quite likely much slower than a single thread implementation that is more optimized. In particular in the end it is memory that is accessed and things are moved everywhere thanks to the merge sort way of processing. Basically that algorithm would be limited by main memory performance/cache rather than CPU except if the cost of comparison is huge.

But technically there, you implementation is not thread safe and isn't waiting for the sub tasks to finish.

So typically the var left & right are sorted potentially later on by another thread but are immediatelly merged without waiting into a single sorted result.

You need for merge to wait for left & right to have first been sorted and only then to merge the results.

If you don't wait the execution will happen concurrently on a non thread safe data structure and the program will behave wrongly.

Comment: The possible implementations are endless, really. Quite a few would mean reimplementing the fork/join framework. Basically the merge could call the 2 get on the future and merge once it is available. That would be the most simple one. And the result is whatever you want like the sorted linked it or a boolean that says 'I finished'. This may be just a flag.

Comment: You should not shutdown your executor as the "sort" function is called recursively, you should let the task finish as expected, among other things.

Comment: For the memory, the problem is if you Executor.newCachedThreadPool() you'll create thread as needed, so up to n * Log(n) thread, so that more than the system can handle and yes the error you get is normal. It mean that it will not work well with the get() as you start the thread eargerly. A better approach would be to schedule the tasks per layer like sort 2 consecutive value at the time 2 by two, then upper layer merging 2x2 to get 4 consecutive values sorted and so on.

Comment: This way you can schedule all the tasks of a layer with the number of available thread on your pool, wait for all of them to be finished and then go with the next layer... But this become more and more complex. Get was the naive solution each thread wait for its dependencies to be ready. In this way (likely how fork/join does it), you first execute the dependencies, and then only when they are all available execute the next step. That allow you to use only few threads.

Comment: With a fixed number of thread, on your current implementation, the thread are waiting for task that will be never run as there no more thread available to run them. Hence the issue

Comment: But an optimized merge sort all on a single thread would likely much better than any of these multi thread version.